# UnirestException: connect timed out on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, connection-timeout, unirest

At work, I am trying to deploy a java 8-based application on Tomcat 7 server.

The application should call some RESTful api based on another server (which is still ours). By reading some resources online I decided to use a HTTP request client library called [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html).

I tried to call the api using Postman and everything works fine.
I deployed my application on my LOCAL Tomcat 7 server and it runs smoothly without problems and Unirest does its job correctly.

When I deploy the application on the Tomcat 7 server, every Unirest call, leads to a connect timeout.

This is the stacktrace:

```
    com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to srv-erp2web.rold.corp:80 [srv-erp2web.rold.corp/192.168.5.100] failed: connect timed out
        at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:143)
        at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
        at com.rold.industry.api.common.ApiCaller.getAccessToken(ApiCaller.java:66)
        at com.rold.industry.context.ContextListener.contextInitialized(ContextListener.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5010)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5504)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:553)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1648)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:284)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to srv-erp2web.rold.corp:80 [srv-erp2web.rold.corp/192.168.5.100] failed: connect timed out
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:138)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
        ... 57 more
```

I haven't find any clue on the internet about how this can happen. The really strange thing is that Unirest calls correctly the api on my local Tomcat.

Here a snapshot of the code that I use to call the api:

```
public static String getAccessToken() {
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "calling smartfabauth to get authentication token");
        String accessToken = "";
        try {
            Unirest.setTimeouts(0, 0); // NO TIMEOUT
            HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post(POST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT)
                    .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .body("grant_type=" + GRANT_TYPE + "&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET + "&scope=" + SCOPE)
                    .asJson();

            accessToken = response.getBody().getObject().getString("access_token");

        } catch (UnirestException | JSONException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "[Exception] getAccessToken", e);
        }

        logger.log(Level.FINE, "authentication token obtained");
        return accessToken;
    }
```

Note that `POST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT`, `GRANT_TYPE`, `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET` and `SCOPE` are some constants declared in class necessary to correctly call the api.

Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect it could be a `proxy`/`firewall` issue. Can you try pinging `srv-erp2web.rold.corp:80` from the machine where tomcat is running?

Comment: You can run `tracert`/`traceroute` as well from the same machine.

Comment: I tried to ping: 

ping -c3 srv-erp2web.rold.corp

I receive: 

PING srv-erp2web.rold.corp (192.168.5.100) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- srv-erp2web.rold.corp ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2015ms

Comment: So, try to find out the cause for this packet loss? Is there any proxy/firewall ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is a `firewall/proxy` issue.

You can check the connectivity by pinging `srv-erp2web.rold.corp` from the machine where you want to run Tomcat 7.

If you see packet loss, try below `tracert`(windows) or `traceroute`(*nix) machines.

Usual syntax is `tracert srv-erp2web.rold.corp`

Above tracert shows the request path from source to destination. And also tells where the request is failing.

If the packet loss is because of proxy server, provide `proxy host, port and credentials` if any.

If the packet loss is because of `firewall, enable the port`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As you suspected, it was firewall issues. Thanks a lot for the hint! +1 and accepted!

Comment: Glad to know it helped you!